# Django displaying a static image through a variable from models that is in a JSON object

Tags: html, django, django-models, model, static

I have been trying to display an image using Django in my HTML.

Normally do display a static file somebody would do:

```
<img src="{% static 'user_profile_pics/pfp_2.jpg' %}" >
```

This image static file has been stored in the variable picture in my models.py.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    picture = models.TextField(max_length=500)
```

The user selects the image they want to choose as their profile image. The views.py file is below with the profile definition having the request JSON dictionary with the variable picture being assigned to the model profile.picture.

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
    return render (request, "profile.html", {"userinfo": {'bio': profile.bio, 'picture': profile.picture}}) 
    

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        confirm_password = request.POST['confirm_password']
        bio = request.POST['bio']
        picture = request.POST['picture']
        
        if password==confirm_password:
            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.info(request, 'Username is already taken')
                return redirect(register)
            elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.info(request, 'Email is already taken')
                return redirect(register)
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
                user.save()
                
                profile = Profile(bio=bio, picture=picture, user=user)
                profile.save()
                
                return redirect('login_user')


        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Both passwords are not matching')
            return redirect(register)
            

    else:
        return render(request, 'registration.html')
```

Next up, displaying the bio and picture within the profile html works like this.

```
<div id = "userprofiletext">
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a class="text" >Your Description is: , {{bio}}</a>
        <img src= {{userinfo.picture}} />
{% endif %}
</div>
```

Before implementing the JSON, the bio managed to display. I believe something must be done in the HTML to get it to display and need some help. The picture when displaying on my page does not register but when debugging it is clear that 'picture' is picture file link. The picture on the page never shows up.

I have tried to figure out displaying the bio and picture as they have been correctly passed into the models. There is a django load static line at the top of my HTML file page as well.

Edit:

Everything looks normal in this picture yet it is still not displaying?

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndCTA.jpg)

Comment: What is the value of `userinfo.picture`? This is JSON and the django mapping may not be correct automatically based on how you converted it. For the `picture` field in your model, the URL would be found via `picture.url`, so in my head your issue is saving that value correctly to JSON

Comment: `user_profile_pics/pfp_1.jpg` is what is the value. So, do I just change `<img src = {{userinfo.picture}}}} />` by adding .url to the end of the Django line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `{{userinfo.picture}}` in double quotes

```
 <img src="{{userinfo.picture}}" />
```

Comment: I have already done that for my HTML. It is in the 3rd code box on the fourth line.

Comment: You haven't added any quotes around userinfo.picture in either your views.py or HTML. If you want to pre-render the quotes in your views.py, you'll have to do something like this:

{"userinfo": {'bio': profile.bio, 'picture': $'"{profile.picture}"'}}

Comment: This could work! However, I do not understand that dollar sign? It throws a syntax error... The profile page is already rendered in urls.py

Comment: My apologies. The $”…” should be f”…”. I accidentally defaulted to C# syntax 